# Jackrabbit Deployment Model 2 FOR Java APPLICATION not web stuff

Tags: deployment, jackrabbit

I am trying to write a Java Enterpise app using the Java Content Repository Deployment Model 2, which the Jackrabbit site illustrates as a "J2EE Servelet Container." If I am not mistaken, a servelet container is not appropriate for a general shared j2ee resource. It is specifically described in the context of JSPs or WebApps.

I want Jackrabbit running in Geronimo along with my Java Beans for a Server AND SERVE JAVA CLIENT APPS, NOT WEB PAGES. The Jackrabbit site hints of such a a deployment, but to my eyes is only confusing thereafter. Guidance along these lines seems impossible to come by as literally everything seems to be oriented toward web apps.

I am trying to use the Geronimo with Tomcat 7 and Axis 2 distribution. It's directory structure contains nothing identifiable as Tomcat specific, rendering instuctions on the Jackrabbit site somewhat useless. In an effort to further understand them, all I find are web app related articles. I'm sure it's possible, and probably fairly simple, to do what I want. I just can't seem to put my finger on the right information.

Comment: I think you just need to read up about JNDI. The jackrabbit docs give an example of using a jackrabbit/JNDI/tomcat combo.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this, got diverted for a while and resumed to have a catastropic disk failure. I've finally gotten on top of it, largely by slogging through the API docs.

With respect to JNDI, Geronimo has its own naming environment for its applications.

A large part of the problem is the jackrabbit page(s) are a mess. Interleaved examples no longer work. There used to be a couple of pages (on the Day Software site, I think) documenting enterprise app usage, but I can't find them.

My biggest obstacle was understanding deployment of the resource adapter, which is wrapped up with my app when the whole thing is deployed to Geronimo. I was not sure if this was the case, or if the adapter was deployed to Geronimo by itself, then the application deployed.

When I have this working, I am going to make a page about it.